# Manage organization profiles: no profiles show up!

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, profile-sync, organization-profile

We're currently trying to implement an organization-chart by using the organization profiles. However, in the organization profile management-view show no profiles up - even the root profile is missing.

The strange thing is, the view shows "1" organization profile in the numbered profile-summary in the left upper corner. Therefore, i checked the corresponding SQL-tables `dbo.OrganizationProfile` & `dbo.OrganizationProfileValue`.
And this seems to be the place, where the summary has it's origin. Creating a new profile lets increase the summary of profiles as well as their corresponding SQL-data-rows show up in these tables. But they are still not accessible from central administration.

Setting up a new organization profile - based upon a subtype or not - leads to the same behaviour: the profile is not visible but shows up in the summary and is added to the database correctly.

The user-profile synchronization-service is running fine - which means, it does not gain any export or import-errors and it synchronizes all AD-attributes perfectly.

**Question:** what am i missing, how am i able to fix the behaviour of the organization-profiles?

Answer (score 1):

Best way to setup User Profiles in Sharepoint is to follow a guide like [Harbar's](http://www.harbar.net/articles/sp2010ups2.aspx) one. You will find it easily.

Did you check the 2 User Profiles services? Are they working fine?

The 1 is normal in the upper corner. SharePoint to run needs an Active Directory that's your organization profile.

Comment: I didn't mention it but our profile synchronization is working perfectly - we're able to export attributes into the AD as well as importing them. Sorry for that - i will fix that.

Comment: So for my understanding of how org-profiles work i tried to add org-profiles which reference to the root-organization. But i am unable to pick the root-org as "parent" and i'm not able see and modify the root-org-profile in the org-management.

Comment: Are you sure the user you grant to access the AD can read it? I don't remember exactly which rights he needs but generally when I delegate control I grant him on most of the options available. Try with another elevated account, just to see.

Comment: As mentioned before, the AD-synchronization works perfectly. We approved it with the MIISClient.

Answer (score 0):

Finally we decided to use not any organization-profiles. It seems like they're mentioned to be realized as different AD-roots in bigger companies, having different branches with own AD-structures.